# ER Diagram in Pgadmin for Postgresql in Ubuntu or Debian OS

Tags: postgresql, ubuntu, debian, pgadmin, erd

Please suggest how to create **ER-diagram** in PGAdmin or any other Debian package.

Answer (score 0):

You can use dbeaver to do this. It allows you to export the ER diagram as png/svg etc.

DBeaver - https://dbeaver.io/
Git ref - https://github.com/dbeaver/dbeaver/wiki/Installation

Double click on a schema (eg, Schemas->public->Tables) and open the "ER Diagram" tab (next to "Properties" tab)

Answer (score 0):

Beta Version in Pgadmin Does provide services for the ER diagram